# Google Calendar not showing locale-specific holiday (Father's Day)

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I'm not sure what went wrong, but today (March 19) was [Father's Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father%27s_Day) here in Italy, but my calendar did not show up the event. I've tried creating a new Google account, to see if the problem would go away, and here is what I saw:

Four calendars were created by default:

**My calendars**

- John Higginstyne
- Birthdays
- Google Tasks

**Other calendars**

- Holidays in Italy

(another Google account which had already been set up and been in use also had another entry named "Holidays in United Kingdom" and others).

---

Anyways, why isn't the event "Father's Day" showing up in Google Calendar? I even tried clicking on the squares next to each calendar so that such squares would become colored (hence enabled, I would guess).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There might be downloadable calendars with the holidays you want, which you could import into Google Calender.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to find [this link](http://www.calendario-di-santi-patroni-e-citta-d-italia.com/catholic-saints-calendar.html) which has a Google Calendar button which takes you to [this link](http://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=0a94g9qvu808mshghvg038c4n0%40group.calendar.google.com) which adds a Google Calendar in the "Other calendars" section. [This site](http://www.santodelgiorno.it/) also has pictures; too bad pictures don't seem to be supported by Google Calendar (at least not at the moment).

Comment: No idea why this post has attracted the nutters in the last 24 hours (probably being linked to from a conservative site) but this is relevant for answering the actual question:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/94677/how-to-add-uk-mothering-sunday-and-fathers-day-to-google-calendar

Answer (score 1):

Google only shows Public Holidays in the selected country.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father%27s_Day#.C2.A0Italy):

> In Italy, according to the Roman Catholic tradition, fathers are celebrated on ... March 19. It is not a public holiday.

It is not a public holiday, and therefore does not show in "Holidays in Italy."

Comment: Fair enough. But there are a number of days (even for instance Mother's Day, Halloween in the US, Carnival, or even saints' days (in Italy each day is supposed to have a Saint's name associated with it, and if a person's name is the same as that of the Saint's name, then a small feast is celebrated to honor such person).

Comment: Since it would be a relatively lengthy and unproductive process to add all of this by hand, is there a script or plugin somewhere which updates a calendar according to the special days (which may not correspond to holidays as you pointed out) for all countries such calendar is set up to support? How can I get Google Calendar to display the celebration names of such days?

Comment: (PS: I'd like to upvote you, but I don't have enough points).